# Jmeter - will the performance decrease if there is any dependent between two API?

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter iam calling second API based on first API token(XAUTH TOKEN).
so in this case second API will wait for first API's token.
will it increase the second API response time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The second request can only be started, after the first request has returned, but the response time is always measured for a single request. So the response time of your second request is measured independent of the response time of your first request and is not a sum of both requests.